# Why is there a superconducting dome in superconductors?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

Generally speaking, by the well-known BCS theory, the more carrier density( density of state at Fermi surface) leads to higher critical temperature.

However, in many researches, people fond that the relation between critical temperature and carrier density is not simple. There is a superconducting dome in phase diagram, no matter what carriers are electrons or holes. There exist a critical carrier density which gives the maximum critical temperature.

Why is there a superconducting dome?

What reduces the critical temperature when carrier density is higher than the critical carrier density? What is the physical reason?

By the way, I don't think it can be simply explained by inducing disorder or impurity when doping. It is usually happen in chemical doping. However, there are many electrostatic doping researching on this topic, and usually it would only induce high carrier density without impurity or disorder, but also show similar nature of superconducting dome.

Comment: Doping does not necessarily increase the density of states at the Fermi surface. Regardless, I believe the origin of the dome is still an open problem. One way to look at it is that doping changes the Fermi surface. This then affects the interactions between electrons and spin fluctuations that are responsible for superconductivity. When the system is overdoped, the interactions become weaker and $T_c$ decreases.

Comment: You may be interested in this paper: Sci. Rep. 2, 381 (2012).